# Que properties de Spring boot/JPA debería usar si quiero utilizar las tablas y datos ya creados en mariadb?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, mariadb

tengo los siguientes archivos en mi proyecto de spring boot.
Y quisiera utilizar las tablas y poder consumir esos datos con mi api restful.
Yo tengo el create-drop pero eso crea y borra cada vez que ejecuto la aplicación y están vacías las tablas porque no inserto nada durante el create-drop.
Pero ya tengo datos en las tablas y no puedo traerlos, el get con postman me trae un 200 pero vació.
Mi error esta en la logica de las properties.

```
   # Datasource configurations.

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create



# Datasource configurations.
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/aulas_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driverclassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop



spring.main.banner-mode=off
server.servlet.context-path = /api
server.port = 8090
# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true


# Logger configurations.
logging.level.com.capgemini.serviciosya = DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.data  = DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type = TRACE


# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect  = org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate
entitymanager.packagesToScan = ar.edu.unaj.reports.entity

spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `update` el cual te permite actualizar el schema sobre el cual estás trabajando.

La propiedad `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` es específica de Spring Data JPA y es su manera de especificar un valor que finalmente se pasará a Hibernate bajo la propiedad que conoce, `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.

Los valores `create`, `create-drop`, `validate` y `update` básicamente influyen en la forma en la que se manipulará el esquema de la base de datos en el inicio.

Así que la lista de opciones posibles son:

- `validate`: validar el esquema, no realiza cambios en la base de
  datos.
- `update`: actualizar el esquema.
- `create`: crea el esquema, destruyendo los datos anteriores.
- `create-drop`: elimina el esquema cuando `SessionFactory` se cierre explícitamente, generalmente cuando la aplicación se detiene.

Comment: Osea solo deberia poner update en las properties?yo estoy haciendo solo gets con la api y necesito usar los datos que estan insertados.

Comment: si yo cargo un .sql en la carpeta resource en las properties deberia poner lo siguiente? spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

Comment: @Diego para la primera pregunta de utilizar `update`, sí, para que no se altere tu schema deberas utilizar `update`. Para la segunda pregunta de cargar el .sql, aunque no lo describiste en la pregunta inicialmente, sí, con `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` se inicializa un archivo `.sql` que debe de estar ubicado en la carpeta `resources`.